# Regex spits out extra empty array

Tags: php, regex

```
$input = "some words go here priority: p1,p2 -rank:3 status: not delayed";

$pattern = "/(\S+):\s*(.*?)(?=\S+:|$)|(.*?)(?=\S+:|$)/";

preg_match_all($pattern, $input, $matches);
```

Example: http://regex101.com/r/yM0wO1#pcre

The above pattern ends up outputting an extra empty array at the end. (See Match 5 in the example)

Everything else is the way I expect it to be...

How can I prevent the extra empty array?

EDIT:
BACKGROUND INFO

I have data formatted as such:

```
some words go here priority: p1,p2 -rank:3 status: not delayed
```

Basically I need to retrieve each set of data that corresponds to the colon name.

Ideally if I could end up with an array structure such that

```
'' => 'some words go here'
priority => 'p1,p2'
-rank    => 3
status   => 'not delayed'
```

A few caveats:

```
keywords will not have a defining colon-word (keywords are just placed in the front)

keywords will not always exist (might just be colon-words)

colon-words will not always exist (might just be keywords)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way would be to **split** instead of matching it.

```
(?=\s\S+:)
```

Each string would contain the key-value pair or only value if there's no key

Comment: Well, not quite... I've added some background info to hopefully make clearer what I need.

Comment: @kylex split it instead of matching it with above regex.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
(\S+):\s*(.*?)(?=\S+:|$)|(.*?)(?=\S+:)
```

Comment: Added some needed background info which explains the caveats